# How can I get the position of an HTML element when the browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a function that draw a CANVAS line and make its get the same coordinates of a `<div>` by using offsetLeft. The line searchs the same position of the `<div>` making its get glued on the `<div>`  It is working good BUT ONLY when the page loads and the browser refreshs.

```
drawCanvas() {
  const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const lineH = c.getContext("2d");      
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  const lineV = c.getContext("2d");   

 const positionCanvas = () => {
   lineV.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);    
   const divPosition = document.querySelector('.myDiv').offsetLeft  
   lineV.fillStyle = "grey";
   lineV.fillRect(divPosition , 0, 2, window.innerHeight);
   lineV.fill();
}

  positionCanvas() 

  window.onresize = () => {    
  lineV.height = window.innerHeight; 
  positionCanvas()     
}
```

I would like to make it work good everytime even and especially when I'm handling the resizing of the window. How can I solve it?

**Example:**

1. The page is loaded: 
   OK!!! The canvas line is glued on `<div>`
2. While the user is manually resizing the window's browser: 
   NOT WORKING!!! The canvas search the `<div>` but not get glued on its,
   there is a distance between both.
3. After the stop of the browser resizing: 
    NOT WORKING!!! the lline still separated from the `<div>`
4. Refresh the browser in a new position:
   OK!!! canvas line is glued on `<div>`

Comment: create a snippet/jsFiddle including all your code.

Comment: lineV is not declared. Please share the complete code.

Comment: Code edited with variable declaration

Comment: Edited code with this line:
`lineV.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Just put the function `drawCanvas()` into the `window.onresize` rather the `positionCanvas()`.

Just like that:

```
 window.onresize = () => {  
  drawCanvas()    
}
```